# encode curl GET request and construct the URL

Tags: bash, curl

i've the following example dynamic generated url for GET request

```
http://api.jwplatform.com/v1/videos/create?api_format=json&api_key=dgfgfg&api_nonce=554566&api_timestamp=1500296525&custom.videoId=905581&description=تقليد بداية العام&downloadurl=http://media.com/media/mymedia.mp4&sourceformat=mp4&sourcetype=url&sourceurl=http://media.com/media/mymedia.mp4&title=الغطس بالمياه الباردة.. تقليد بداية العام&api_signature=5cd337198ead0768975610a135e2
```

which is include the following vars

```
api_key=
api_nonce=
api_timestamp=
custom.videoId=
description=
downloadurl=
sourceurl=
title= 
api_signature=
sourceformat=mp4
sourcetype=url
```

i;m tring to get send curl GET command and get the response back i always failed for 2 reason ,

1. the urls in the request should be encoded utf8
2. and the 2nd one the i always get curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host for
   each vars like its not taking the url as one url and break it into
   different calls for example

   curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'بداية'

   - Input domain encoded as `ANSI_X3.4-1968'
   - Failed to convert العام&downloadurl=http: to ACE; System iconv failed
   - getaddrinfo(3) failed for العام&downloadurl=http::80

curl -X -G -v -H "Content: agent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://api.jwplatform.com/v1/videos/create?api_format=json&{vars}

and tips how i can reach this  and construct the curl command in the right format

Comment: Make sure you enclose the URL in single quotes so it isn't understood as multiple arguments. I feel like this could be the reason the arabic characters are parsed as hosts.

Comment: also i gave i give it a shot but its not working

Comment: When I said single-quotes, I really meant quotes. Both single and double quotes will make the string be understood as a single argument rather than each space-separated part understood as an argument. The difference is that there won't be any parameter expansion inside single-quotes, so avoid them if you're using variables to construct your URL. Now you probably still have a problem with unicode characters, which you should be able to avoid by urlencoding the parameters values

Comment: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command) should provide a better way than doing this by hand